Portal Bridge block height exceeded
I've got a transaction stuck in portalbridge wormhole for the last 20 hours. is there a way i can increase the fees? or is there a technical issue? i'm getting "signature has expired: block height exceeded"
Thanks

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?
